# What is the difference between an applicationQueuePlayer and an applicationMusicPlayer?

Tags: ios, mpmusicplayercontroller

In the Apple documentation, it says

> The application queue music player provides more functionality and greater control over the music played than the application music player.

But what control and functionality is that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According the declaration, the **MPMusicPlayerController** inheritance it from **NSObject**,and 
**MPMusicPlayerApplicationController** inheritance it from **MPMusicPlayerController**.

So,it is clearly that,***NSObject*** =>  ***MPMusicPlayerController*** => ***MPMusicPlayerApplicationController***
[image]
Then,**MPMusicPlayerApplicationController** have all func of **MPMusicPlayerController**,
the More func is ***Changing the Queue Contents*** added, there are two methods offered about it.
[image: the pic show]
In general , you just use MPMusicPlayerController can do many things,hope to help you.

Comment: Thank you, that was helpful.

Comment: @mmm If the reply is helpful, please do not forget to accept it as answer( click the ✔ in the upper left corner of this answer) and vote it up, it will help others who have similar issue.